Is there a digital MONIAC machine?
Is there an app/site that reproduces Philipp's MONIAC hydraulic machine and lets users experiment and learn (perhaps better that through simple video-watching)?

I seem to recall the Science Museum had a computer simulation set up as a kiosk next to the original machine.

Launched last week - a complete working digital Phillips Machine! https://www.ft.com/content/547a3fea-378d-45ec-a2cb-cb157ea7a9b4
